# ExpressJS: Why does this output [] on the first GET, and then the next GET returns the data from the previous?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

I am experimenting with Express and MongoDB, and have a functional API server that can add, update, delete, and retrieve a single post. The issue I have run into is returning all of the documents from Mongo.

I have a GET route that outputs the results, except it does not behave as I imagined it would. When you run this, the first GET request to /notes returns and empty array, i.e. []

```
let notes =[];
app.get('/notes', (req, res) => {
    async function getNotes() {
      try {
        await db.collection('notes').find().forEach(function (myDoc) {
          notes.push(myDoc);
        })
      } catch(err) {
        console.log(err)
      }
      console.log(notes);
      res.send((notes));
    }
    getNotes();
  });
```

On the *second* GET to /notes, however, the data that was pushed into notes[] is returned, and it is then overwritten by the newly pushed data.

Can anyone help me fill in the blank spot in my understanding of this? I imagine there is something that I just didn't understand along the way.

Edit***

I have experimented with this a bit, and am still running into the same issues.

```
let array= [];
async function getNotes() {
try {
  await db.collection('notes').find().toArray(function (err, notesArray) {
    array = notesArray;
  })
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err)
}
console.log(array);
return array;
}
app.get('/notes', (req, res) => {
  getNotes();
  res.send(array);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MongoDB's [`.toArray()`](https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#toArray) won't both invoke a callback and return a Promise.

> **Returns**:
>
> Promise if no callback passed

And, `await` depends on the `Promise`, so you won't be able to use the callback as well.

Though, one isn't really necessary. When the promise resolves, `await` will return the array of documents, allowing you to assign that to `array` or any other variable.

```
try {
  array = await db.collection('notes').find().toArray();
}
```

Comment: Wow, so simple and clear. Now I understand why I was running into this issue over and over again in various areas. Thank you so very much!!

Comment: I wish I could give you an upvote, but I'm not cool enough yet! <3